# C# Method that acts like "break;" to consuming code?

Tags: c#, break

Is there a way to write a method, so that it acts like break; to the consuming code?  I'm trying to replace a bunch of places where I do this:

```
if (flag == true)
{
    break;
}
```

I am writing a console application that uses a while loop with a switch case to show a menu.  I have a bunch of repetitive code that I want to extract into methods.  Specifically the methods that take user input need to be able to go back to the main menu.  I've been doing this with a boolean (flag) as an out parameter to these methods.

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Although I **strongly** discourage this, you may be able to break from a loop simply by throwing an exception:

```
public void AssertFlag(bool flag)
{
    if(flag)
    {
         throw new Exception(); //You can use a more specific type
    }
}
```

You woud call this function from inside your loop:

```
while(...)
{
     // ... Code here
     AssertFlag(flag);
     // ... Code here
}
```

Please note that if you don't handle your exception properly up in the call stack, then your application will crush.

Comment: @Downvoter, Please take a second to leave a comment explaining the downvote and how I can improve my answer